# Creating a keystore file.. unsigned .APK

Tags: android, cordova, apk, unsigned

I created an unsigned .APK and realized I needed a signed copy to push it to Google Play. Is it possible I can create a keystore file separately? I am using build.phonegap.com and there is an option to insert a keyfile and rebuild. I have lost of my workspace so suggestions on getting a keystore file would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) to generate your key, [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) to sign it, and [zipalign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html) to align your final apk.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Comment: How do I download keytool? I am using a mac.

Comment: It should be installed by default? Try the `keytool` command from Terminal.

Comment: Ah, I see.I created the key through keytool and trying to use jarsigner to sign it. Mine is called `test.apk` but I tried typing in the terminal: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs test.apk and it said `No such file or directory`. Any clue?

Comment: You have to navigate to the directory with your apk or type in the absolute path to it.